# Where do you set the button size of a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have my own custom UISegmentedControl subclass. It's buttons are bigger than the standard size. Each button is 100.0 points wide.

```
@implementation SegmentedControlExplore

- (id) init
{
    return [super  
        initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            @"Uno", 
            @"Dos", 
            nil
        ]
    ];
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.numberOfSegments; i++) {
        [self setWidth:100.0 forSegmentAtIndex:i];
    }
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```

When I attempt to use this in my controller, I could not center it in my UINavigationBar.

```
SegmentedControl* sc = [[[SegmentedControl alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:sc];
sc.center = self.navigationController.navigationBar.center;
```

It's off-center to the right. The reason is because the button size setting actually gets called after its center property gets changed. So where should I move my button size setting so it gets done first? I tried moving it to init, but the size did not get changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `layoutSubviews` function with this code.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.numberOfSegments*100, 44);
    self.center = self.superview.center;

    CGRect frame = self.frame;

    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y-20, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    }

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.numberOfSegments; i++) {
        [self setWidth:100 forSegmentAtIndex:i];
    }

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```